# mutt: a hotkey to return to INBOX?

Tags: mutt

I assume there's no such default key, am I right?

So, in order to achieve this I have to define something like this?

```
macro index   gi "<change-folder>=INBOX<Enter>"              "go to Inbox"
macro browser gi "<exit><Enter><change-folder>=INBOX<Enter>" "go to Inbox"
macro pager   gi "<exit><change-folder>=INBOX<Enter>"        "go to Inbox"
...
```

Or may be there's a fancier way? If by any chance you have something related in your configs, I'd be grateful if you could share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. There are no such default keys.
But you can simplify your calls.

```
# Switch between mailboxes (in case you have multiple mailboxes)
macro index,pager <f2> "<change-folder>+<MAILBOX1>/INBOX<enter>"
macro index,pager <f3> "<change-folder>+<MAILBOX2>/INBOX<enter>"
```

In addition to that I have the sibebar enabled and use the arrow keys to switch folders.

```
# Sidebar navigation
bind index,pager <down>   sidebar-next
bind index,pager <up>     sidebar-prev
bind index,pager <right>  sidebar-open
```

EDIT: [Here](https://blog.ploth.xyz/blog/2017/10/31/dank-mutt-setup.html) can find my whole `.muttrc`

EDIT2: Regarding the comment to have conditional mappings: Yes this is possible in case the condition is another mail account. You can have account specific configuration files where you are able to overwrite existing mappings. Load them via a folder hook which get executed as soon as you enter a corresponding folder.

Put this in your `.muttrc`

```
folder-hook MAILBOX1/*   source ~/.mutt/accounts/MAILBOX1
folder-hook MAILBOX2/*   source ~/.mutt/accounts/MAILBOX2
```

Create account specific configurations in `~/.mutt/accounts/MAILBOX#`

For example, switch between two different INBOX folders with the same key.

`~/.mutt/accounts/MAILBOX1` contains:

```
macro index,pager <f2> "<change-folder>+MAILBOX2/INBOX<enter>"
```

`~/.mutt/accounts/MAILBOX2` contains:

```
macro index,pager <f2> "<change-folder>+MAILBOX1/INBOX<enter>"
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, I understand, it's not possible in any way to have a conditional mapping? Like, if in `index` but the active folder is not INBOX, then do A, and if in `index` AND in INBOX, then do B. Right?

Comment: You can even do that iff your condition relates to another mailbox (second mail account). You can have account specific configuration files where you can overwrite existing mappings. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
macro index H g!\rm
macro index S g=sent\rm
macro index V g!!\rm
```

is what I have to go to the "home", "sent", or "previous" mailbox via "g" (change-folder). You may or may not need the "m" (move entry to middle of screen) at the end.